How to do batching in Redisson while using RMapCache.getAll?
Can someone let me know why there is no batchSize in RMapCache.getAll(keys) unlike RMapCache.putAll?
Does RMapCache.getAll(keys) internally do some batching while getting the keys from Redis? If not what is the recommended way to do getAll when there are a lot of elements in the keys set? Do I have to manually split the keys into small batches and then make multiple invocations of RMapCache.getAll(keys) ?

This is answered in Redisson forum. Cross-posting the reply for completeness

At the moment you need to split input keys into chunks manually.

